# Changing values in an array with AngularJS $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a 2D array that is iterated through via `ng-repeat`. This array is actually part of a spreadsheet app I am building, where the initial values in the spreadsheet are that of the array. I wrote a function that would update this array as the user changed input values, however, I've been informed that I need to use the `$watch` method instead of an `onchange` method.

I'm really thrown off because I don't understand how I can change the initial array's values through the `$watch` method. I see that it detects change, but I want it to keep track of that change and actually alter the initial array.

**Here is my Javascript, including the beginnings of a `$watch` method:**

```
sheet= function($scope, $parse){
    $scope.columns = headers;
    $scope.rows = allData.length;
    $scope.cells = {};
    $scope.$watch(
        function() {console.log("Change!");},
    );
    $scope.values = allData.map(function(c,row){
        return c.map(function(data){
            return {
                content: data,
                model: null,
                color: makeColors(data)
            };
        });
    });
};

changeData = function(row, col, data){
    allData[row][col] = data;
};
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="sheet">
    <table>
        <tr class="column-label">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</td>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <td class="row-label" ng-repeat="data in value">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="inputValue"  ng-model="data.content" class="{{data.color}}" onchange="changeData({{$parent.$index}},{{$index}},this.value)">
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, I call the changeData function using the `$parent.$index` and `$index` values, which allow me to access and change the initial array. I'm unsure how to do this via `$watch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $watch is missing the value it's watching. It won't do anything without that.

But why are you going through such trouble to update your model? Your model is updated automatically when you bind ng-model to an input.

Here is a plunker showing how I would approach it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oxu1NV?p=preview

Comment: What should I bring up in an alert or print to the console to see my updated array? I have tried allData but it remains unchanged, and sheet.$scope.values are undefined. I guess I mostly just don't understand what is changing and what happens when it's changed. I see it is bound to data.content, but that doesn't do anything that I've noticed.

Comment: If you notice in my plunker, I output the drinks model in a <pre> block at the bottom of the page. You can see data being updated there if you edit any of the drink ingredients. I usually just output it in the view so I can see changes happening to the model in real time. If a change is happening in the controller, then I use console.log.

Comment: In your case, your model is returning function calls. It might be simpler to just build a complex JS object with the actual data.

Comment: Since it's bound with the input, you helped point me in the right direction of having everything working via `ng-change`; however, how would I access the color or any other field that could be in the values? Can the input be bound to multiple things?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "access". To output them?

Comment: In your example you used `ng-change="drink.row='yellow'"` If I wanted to change the color as well as the contents, how would I include that in a function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33211/discussion-between-user2494584-and-sharondio)